# Prolog - infinite loop

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

I want to check if element is in the middle of list.
I search middle element and next I check if is a member of list, but I get infinite loop.

My predicates:

```
remove_first([_,H1|T], [H1|T]).

remove_last([_],[]).
remove_last([H|T], [H|T2]) :- remove_last(T, T2).

remove_first_and_last([X],[X]).
remove_first_and_last(In, Out) :- 
    remove_first(In, Out1),
    remove_last(Out1, Out).

middle([X], [X]).
middle(In, X) :-
    remove_first_and_last(In, Out),
    middle(Out, X).

member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|T]) :- member(X, T).

is_middle(X, In) :-
    middle(In, Out),
    member(X, Out), !.
```

And when I call `is_middle(1,[2,1,3])` then I get true.
But when I call `is_middle(1,[2,2,3])` then I don't get a result. Interpreter don't interrupt the processing.

Comment: Did you try testing each of your predicates? You should do so to narrow it down. When you call `is_middle(1,[2,2,3])` it calls `middle([2,3,3], Out)`. What happens when you call that? And `middle([2,3,3], Out)` will call `remove_first_and_last([2,3,3], Out)`, so what happens when you call that? Etc....

Comment: factually, I have to correct other predicates. thanks

Comment: It's often useful to use `trace/0`, as in `trace, is_middle(1, [2,2,3])`, because you can probably see the arc of the loop interactively with it.

Comment: What if your list has an even number of elements? What is your expected result? Should, for example, `is_middle(3, [1,2,3,4])` be true?

Comment: ... and should also `is_middle(2, [1,2,3,4])` be true as well?

Answer (score 9):

In a situation as yours, you have two options. Either wade through walls of text of traces as you can see in another answer, or try to reduce first what you have to understand. I prefer the latter for I don't like to read much.

But your major problem is this. You said:

> And when I call `is_middle(1,[2,1,3])` then I get true.

Yes, Prolog found a solution, but it did not find it once but infinitely many times. Just hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>;</kbd> to see this:

```
?- is_middle(1,[2,1,3]).
   true
;  true
;  true
;  true
;  true
;  ... .
```

So, already your first query was problematic. The best way to observe this, is to add **`false`** to this query:

```
?- is_middle(1,[2,1,3]), false.
   loops.
```

Now, let's try to reduce the size of the query. We can narrow it down to:

```
?- is_middle(1,[1]), false.
   loops.
```

With this we can now look at your program. Before anything else I'll remove the cut. It is misplaced anyway.

To understand what is actually happening, I will narrow down your program by inserting **`false`** into it. With these extra goals it is possible to eliminate a lot of unnecessary detail. And still, the remaining program called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) is of relevance to us, if it is still looping.

```
remove_first_and_last([X],[X]).
remove_first_and_last(In, Out) :- false,
    remove_first(In, Out1),
    remove_last(Out1, Out).

middle([X], [X]) :- false.
middle(In, X) :-
    remove_first_and_last(In, Out),
    middle(Out, X), false.

is_middle(X, In) :-
    middle(In, Out), false,
    member(X, Out).
```

Compare this to your original program! Much less reading. To fix the problem you have to fix something in the remaining fragment. I suggest to remove the fact `remove_first_and_last([X],[X]).` This fact suggests that something is removed, but for this very case, nothing is removed.

---

For a solution using a [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) directly:

```
is_middle(E, Es) :-
   phrase(middle(E), Es).

middle(E) --> [E].
middle(E) --> [_], middle(E), [_].
```

That is as short as it can get, but it has a tiny problem: It does not compute the answer determinately. You can see this by looking at the answer:

```
?- is_middle(1, [2,1,3]).
   true
;  false.
```

This `; false` is an indication that Prolog was not able to finish the computation determinately. In other words, some space is left. You might be tempted to use a cut. Resist!

---

If you are really into speed, take the fastest version:

```
is_middle(X, Xs) :-
   Xs = [_|Cs],
   middle_el(Cs, Xs, X).

middle_el([], [X|_], X).
middle_el([_,_|Cs], [_|Xs], X) :-
   middle_el(Cs, Xs, X).
```

---

In case you want @DanielLyons' interpretation which admits even-length lists to have two middle elements, see how easy it is to adopt above grammar definition. Simply add the following two rules:

```
middle(E) --> [E,_].
middle(E) --> [_,E].
```

Alternatively, combine all four rules into one:

```
middle(E) --> [E] | [E,_] | [_,E] | [_], middle(E), [_].
```

For the fastest solution, things are a bit more complex ...

```
is_middle_dl(X, Xs) :-
   Xs = [_|Cs],
   middle_el_dl(Cs, Xs, X).

middle_el_dl([], [X|_], X).
middle_el_dl([_|Cs], Xs, X) :-
   middle_el_dl2(Cs, Xs, X).

middle_el_dl2([], [A,B|_], X) :-
   ( X = A ; X = B ).
middle_el_dl2([_|Cs], [_|Xs], X) :-
   middle_el_dl(Cs, Xs, X).
```

To check it, I use:

```
?- length(Xs, N), N mod 2 =:= 0, is_middle_dl(X, Xs).
   Xs = [X,_A], N = 2
;  Xs = [_A,X], N = 2
;  Xs = [_A,X,_B,_C], N = 4
;  Xs = [_A,_B,X,_C], N = 4
;  Xs = [_A,_B,X,_C,_D,_E], N = 6
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,X,_D,_E], N = 6
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,X,_D,_E,_F,_G], N = 8
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,X,_E,_F,_G], N = 8
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,X,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I], N = 10
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,X,_F,_G,_H,_I], N = 10
;  ... .
```

Comment: @DanielLyons: What is the middle there?

Comment: `middle([1,2], [3,1,2,4])`, and `is_middle(X, [3,1,2,4])` should unify X with 1 and then 2.

Comment: @DanielLyons: But there is nothing in OP's question that demands this.

Comment: @DanielLyons: Anyway, I added two further versions.

Comment: Not explicitly, but I inferred from his use of `member/2` and that his helper predicates return singleton lists instead of a single value. Anyway, it's a trivial change for your code.

Answer (score 6):

Debugging Prolog takes some different skills, so let's take the long road there.

First, let's notice something interesting about your two sample queries. The first one succeeds, and it should; the second one should fail, but instead it loops. This tidbit is a clue: it suggests that we're trying to handle a false case. This is a common mistake among people using Prolog after other languages. In Prolog, it's often enough to be explicit about successful cases and just let failures happen through failed unifications.

The standard tool for debugging Prolog is `trace/0`. The idea is, you activate trace mode and then run your query, like this:

```
?- trace,  is_middle(1,[2,2,3]).
```

The trouble with `trace/0` is that it can take some effort to understand what's happening with it. Each line starts with one of these four verbs: call, exit, redo, or fail. Then there's a number which indicates the nesting level of the call. The call and redo verbs tell you that you're entering a computation; exit and fail tell you a computation is ceasing and the nesting level is about to decrease. Call/exit are the normal case, fail/redo are what makes Prolog special, the non-determinism. In general, an infinite loop will look like some prefix of meaningful work (or possibly not) followed by an endlessly repeating chunk of output from `trace`. And we see that here. Prefix:

```
Call: (8) is_middle(1, [2, 2, 3]) ? creep
Call: (9) middle([2, 2, 3], _G1194) ? creep
Call: (10) remove_first_and_last([2, 2, 3], _G1194) ? creep
Call: (11) remove_first([2, 2, 3], _G1194) ? creep
Exit: (11) remove_first([2, 2, 3], [2, 3]) ? creep
Call: (11) remove_last([2, 3], _G1197) ? creep
Call: (12) remove_last([3], _G1190) ? creep
Exit: (12) remove_last([3], []) ? creep
Exit: (11) remove_last([2, 3], [2]) ? creep
Exit: (10) remove_first_and_last([2, 2, 3], [2]) ? creep
```

Repeating chunk:

```
Call: (10) middle([2], _G1200) ? creep
Exit: (10) middle([2], [2]) ? creep
Exit: (9) middle([2, 2, 3], [2]) ? creep
Call: (9) member(1, [2]) ? creep
Call: (10) member(1, []) ? creep
Fail: (10) member(1, []) ? creep
Fail: (9) member(1, [2]) ? creep
Redo: (10) middle([2], _G1200) ? creep
Call: (11) remove_first_and_last([2], _G1200) ? creep
Exit: (11) remove_first_and_last([2], [2]) ? creep
```

Now you can see it would be much easier to trigger the bad behavior just with this query:

```
[trace]  ?- is_middle(2,[3]).
   Call: (7) is_middle(2, [3]) ? creep
   Call: (8) middle([3], _G398) ? creep
   Exit: (8) middle([3], [3]) ? creep
   Call: (8) member(2, [3]) ? creep
   Call: (9) member(2, []) ? creep
   Fail: (9) member(2, []) ? creep
   Fail: (8) member(2, [3]) ? creep
   Redo: (8) middle([3], _G398) ? creep
   Call: (9) remove_first_and_last([3], _G398) ? creep
   Exit: (9) remove_first_and_last([3], [3]) ? creep
   Call: (9) middle([3], _G401) ? creep
   Exit: (9) middle([3], [3]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) middle([3], [3]) ? creep
   Call: (8) member(2, [3]) ? creep
   Call: (9) member(2, []) ? creep
   Fail: (9) member(2, []) ? creep
   Fail: (8) member(2, [3]) ? creep
   Redo: (9) middle([3], _G401) ? creep
```

Now it should be clear that the problem has to do with the interplay of `middle/2`, `remove_first_and_last/2` and `member/2`. Your definition of `member/2` is exactly the standard definition so it probably isn't to blame. Now, interestingly, you have `middle/2` calling both itself and `remove_first_and_last/2`. And both `middle/2` and `remove_first_and_last/2` have an identical clause: `m([X], [X])`.

This kind of thing is a great generator of infinite recursion, because the first thing `middle/2` does in its *second* clause is exactly what it just tried to do and failed with its own *first* clause. So it can find itself entering a recursive call in the second clause with *exactly the same state it had in an earlier failed call to itself*.

The solution is to look at `remove_first_and_last/2` and realize that your first clause there does *not* actually remove the first and last element. Removing the `remove_first_and_last([X], [X])` clause fixes the code:

```
[trace]  ?- is_middle(2,[3]).
   Call: (7) is_middle(2, [3]) ? creep
   Call: (8) middle([3], _G398) ? creep
   Exit: (8) middle([3], [3]) ? creep
   Call: (8) member(2, [3]) ? creep
   Call: (9) member(2, []) ? creep
   Fail: (9) member(2, []) ? creep
   Fail: (8) member(2, [3]) ? creep
   Redo: (8) middle([3], _G398) ? creep
   Call: (9) remove_first_and_last([3], _G398) ? creep
   Call: (10) remove_first([3], _G398) ? creep
   Fail: (10) remove_first([3], _G398) ? creep
   Fail: (9) remove_first_and_last([3], _G398) ? creep
   Fail: (8) middle([3], _G398) ? creep
   Fail: (7) is_middle(2, [3]) ? creep
false.
```

Both your tests also now work:

```
?- is_middle(1,[2,1,3]).
true.

?- is_middle(1,[2,2,3]).
false.
```

I think you added the base case here out of a sense of duty to have one. But the reality is that if you have a list of one element, it should fail to unify with `remove_first_and_last/2` under any circumstance. This is very similar to handling an error case explicitly with Prolog, which tends to interfere with the working of the machinery.

Now, one thing that's missing is, how do you want to handle even-length lists? What you have right now won't, with or without my change. Even-length lists don't have a middle element; is that what you intend? I suspect it isn't, because of the appearance of `member/2` in `is_middle/2`.

**Comments on `is_middle/2`**

What you have here could be restructured like so:

```
is_middle(X, In) :- middle(In, [X]).
```

Usage of `member/2` isn't buying you anything because `middle/2` can't ever produce a non-singleton list in its second argument. But, if it did, because you had even-length lists, it would be profitable. You could even make this code work that way by adding a third clause to `middle/2`:

```
middle([X,Y], [X,Y]).
```

Now see `middle/2` works on even-length lists like so:

```
?- middle([2,1,3,4], X).
X = [1, 3] ;
false.
```

Now the cut gets you into trouble though. For instance, 1 and 3 are both `is_middle/2`:

```
?- is_middle(1, [2,1,3,4]).
true.

?- is_middle(3, [2,1,3,4]).
true.
```

Unfortunately though, if you ask for middle elements, you just have `1`:

```
?- is_middle(X, [2,1,3,4]).
X = 1.
```

What happened to `3`? You prevented it from being generated with your cut. I am not sure why the cut is here. I think you must have put it in to try and control the infinite recursion, but it doesn't help you, so get rid of it.

Debugging by random addition of cuts is generally not a great idea. A much better approach is using Ulrich Neumerkel's *failure slice* approach (see [this paper](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/papers/PDF/1999-ppdp-corr.pdf) or [search the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failure-slice) for more information).

**DCG bonus**

You can rephrase `remove_first_and_last/2` as a DCG rule:

```
remove_first_and_last --> remove_first, remove_last.
```

Pretty cool, huh? :) That's because the kind of input/output threading you're doing in that rule exactly what DCG rules get transformed into.

**Summary of changes**

```
remove_first_and_last(In, Out) :- 
    remove_first(In, Out1),
    remove_last(Out1, Out).

middle([X], [X]).
middle([X,Y], [X,Y]).
middle(In, X) :-
    remove_first_and_last(In, Out),
    middle(Out, X).
```

Answer (score 6):

```
is_middle(Item,List) :-
    append(Left,[Item|Right],List),
    length(Left,X),
    length(Right,X).
```

Complex solutions are bad solutions, my friend.

```
?- is_middle(X,[1,2,3,4,5]).
X = 3 ;
false.
```

Fully reversible predicate:

```
?- is_middle(3,L).
L = [3] ;
L = [_G13, 3, _G19] ;
L = [_G13, _G19, 3, _G25, _G28] ;
```

Comment: Nice, even if it's quite expensive.

Comment: Nice but does not handle even-length lists, which appears to be part of the OP's intent. E.g. `is_middle(1, [2,1,3,4])`.